# Change Internet Explorer tile to another browser programmatically

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro

It seems to me that if the user installs another browser on Windows 8, the default tile for Internet Explorer should change to that new browser. However, it doesn't seem like Chrome or Firefox currently does this. Is it even possible to replace the IE tile with the tile for another app programmatically?

Comment: I guess I am at a loss on why a tile for one program should point to another program?  The new browser gets its own tile.  The user can unpin the IE tile if they don't want to use it anymore.

Comment: I didn't express myself clearly. I mean moving the new tile to the location where the IE tile is by default, since the user might be used to clicking the tile in that location to launch their web browser.

Comment: There is no programmatic access to rearrange the user's Start page. If it were possible, every app would just move themselves to the front!

Comment: OK, I guess we simply need to leave this to the end user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can't do that.**

All Windows store applications work in a sandbox environment and doesn't have access to core OS api's. App's are restricted to core OS api's so that malicious applications cannot change system setting without user knowing about it.

Answer (score 0):

Start Screen is OS level, and Apps do not have acces to the order of tiles. If they had, user would loose all personalization made as every App would move itself to the first row and column, as Raymond Chen stated.